# Check checkboxes WP All Import

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, advanced-custom-fields, wpallimport

I am trying to make WP All Import select some checkboxes depending on the data in my import CSV.

To import data into custom fields I use the Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) addon.

In there I have some true/false booleans. In my import I have a Yes or No value that determines wether the checkbox should of shouldn't be checked.

Let's say I have set these checkboxes in ACF:

```
optionA : option A (value "yes")
optionB : option B (value "yes")
optionC : option C (value "no")
```

How do I make WP All Import select option A and B, but not option C?

I have tried this, but it didn't seem to work:

```
[IF({optionA[1][contains(.,'yes')]})]optionA : option A,[ENDIF]
[IF({optionB[1][contains(.,'yes')]})]optionB : option B,[ENDIF]
[IF({optionC[1][contains(.,'no')]})]optionC : option C[ENDIF]
```

Answer (score 5):

Found it the same day. I thought I'd answer it here for future references:

```
[IF({optionA[1][contains(.,'yes')]})]optionA,[ENDIF]
[IF({optionB[1][contains(.,'yes')]})]optionB,[ENDIF]
[IF({optionC[1][contains(.,'no')]})]optionC[ENDIF]
```